# How to type a generic function, which is based on the extended generic type of the first parameters type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I've the following definitions:

```
class RESTClient<E extends { id: number }> extends Client {}
class ParticipantClient extends RESTClient<Participant> {}
const createRESTRequestAction = <E extends { id: number }>(client: RESTClient<E>, value?: E) => {};
```

Unfortunately the `createRESTRequestAction` is not typing itself as I want. When I use the following call ..

```
createRESTRequestAction(ParticipantClient, someRecord);
```

.. TypeScript expects `someRecord` to be of type `{ id: number }`. I would like that it expect `E` to be of type `Participant` in this case. How can this be achieved?

Is it possible to infer the generic type of the extended RESTClient?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function its self is generic in this case. You are missing the type parameter when invoking your function. Invoke it like: `createRESTRequestAction<Participant>(ParticipantClient, someRecord);`

Here is a working example (slightly cleaned up):

```
class RestObject {
    id: number
}

class Participant extends RestObject {
    name: string;
}

class RESTClient<E extends RestObject> {}
class ParticipantClient extends RESTClient<Participant> {}
const createRESTRequestAction = <T extends RestObject>(client: RESTClient<T>, value?: T) => {};

const participantClient = new ParticipantClient();

const anyObj = {};

const otherRestObject = {
    id: 1
}

const participant: Participant = {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Robin'
}

createRESTRequestAction<Participant>(participantClient, anyObj); // TypeError, {} not assignable to Participant

createRESTRequestAction<Participant>(participantClient, otherRestObject); // TypeError, "Name" property is missing in otherRestObject parameter

createRESTRequestAction(participantClient, otherRestObject); // Works, transpiler expects the second object to extend RestObject

createRESTRequestAction<Participant>(participantClient, participant); // Works!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there no way to infer the generic type automatically? So I don't have to specify it when I call `createRESTRequestAction`.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to infer the type of one parameter from another without using a type parameter.